# Problem to covert data from CoNLL format to spacy format

Tags: python, nlp, dataset, spacy

**How can I covert data from CoNLL format to spacy format?**

I've executed current code following similar Q&A on stackoverflow: [How to convert from CoNLL format to spacy format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68524723/how-to-convert-from-conll-format-to-spacy-format).

CoNLL

```
I    O
was  O
born O
in   O
1981 B-DateTime
.    O
```

spacyformat

```
[('I was born in 1981.', {'entities': [(14, 17, 'date')]}),
...
]
```

However, I cannot fix the error.

### Code

```sh
$ python3 -m spacy convert input.conllu -c conllu -o ./output/
```

### Error Message

I've read the document, [spacy convert](https://spacy.io/api/cli#convert), but have no idea how to fix the error.

```
Usage: python -m spacy convert [OPTIONS] INPUT_PATH [OUTPUT_DIR]
Try 'python -m spacy convert --help' for help.

Error: no such option: -o
```

### Environment

Python 3.9.1

spaCy version    3.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your first problem is exactly what the error says, there is no `-o` option. The output is just the argument after the input. (I see that in my other answer I put an `-o`, but that was a mistake.)

Your second problems is that `conll` and `conllu` format are not the same thing. The two-column format you have is referred to as conll (or just `ner`) in spaCy.

If you fix those issues the conversion should just work.

I am not sure what your `spacyFormat` line is referring to.